# Mapbox GL JS Repetitively Asking for Location

Tags: javascript, geolocation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm building a site using Mapbox GL JS and I have some maps where I show the user's current location. The problem is that on Safari and Chrome a dialog asking for permission appears every time the page is loaded and that becomes very annoying for the user. This is true regardless of whether the user checks, "remember my answer". Is there a way to prevent this dialog from appearing every time the page is loaded?

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/fomofeed/cjyzxp46d11ht1cnlid5dj183',
    center: [-73.99, 40.737774655438585],
    zoom: 12
});

// Add geolocate control to the map.
var geoTracker = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true
})

map.addControl(geoTracker, 'bottom-right');

$(document).ready(function() {
    geoTracker._geolocateButton.click();
    map.scrollZoom.disable();
})
```

Comment: It's not asking again if the user deny the location permission. Can you test https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API solely in the browsers?